# How to view image in python tkinter using PhotoImage

Tags: python, tkinter

Please am creating an app view and in python and trying to show some images but am getting error. bellow is the code

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()
root.title("Developing Software")
root.iconbitmap("icon.ico")

image = Image.open("tree_50b.JPG").convert("RGB")
my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
my_label = Label(my_img)
my_label.pack()

button_quit = Button(root, text='Exit Program', fg='red', command=root.quit)
button_quit.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-c9a970a4c796>", line 16, in <module>
    my_label = Label(my_img)

  File "C:\anconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)

  File "C:\anconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2292, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)

  File "C:\anconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2269, in _setup
    if master._last_child_ids is None:

AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_last_child_ids'
```

I need help  please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `Label(...)` needs to be a widget, not an image, and the image needs to be a keyword argument.

```
Label(root, image=my_img)
```